# How To make a 3rd Party Api call using React Relay

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am quite new to relay , My idea is to make a 3rd party API call , which returns a JSON object. for example you can consider this URL as an API call which returns a simple JSON.  "http://ip.jsontest.com/". How Do I go about with the react Relay design

Answer (score 0):

It depends..

#### From server?

Just write a graphQL schema as usual but instead of a database request, make an 3rd party API call and use schema `resolvers` if data structure requires it. You might want to add a caching layer if data isn't extremely dynamic because 3rd party API calls *might be* slow (not a rule of thumb).

Now you can get the data *via* Relay Containers as usual. Relay also handles client-side caching!

---

#### From client?

There really isn't Relay design for that because Relay is currently only a glue between graphQL and React. It *might* change with v2. Do as you wish, for example, use a regular function or React method:

```
getMyData() {
    // ajax call or fetch()
}
```

Downside to this is that if you need to reuse that data, client-side caching is your job. Use either Flux / Redux, store it in global variable (not a good practice) or in storages (indexedDB, localStorage *etc*).